# Cake's ACL component and the concept of "ownership"

Tags: cakephp, acl, authentication

I have been futzing around with Cake's Auth/ACL components.  I've read the docs and I've done the tutorial, but I am still not satisfied with what I can actually accomplish with it.  I've seen a [couple](http://aidanlister.com/2009/05/implementing-row-level-access-control-in-cakephp/) of [other](http://jmcneese.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/rmac-is-dead-long-live-rmac/) approaches, but I can't say as I really have a straight winner with either.  In any tutorial/blog post/doc I read, the use case of "ownership" isn't exactly sufficiently covered.

I was hoping to describe my use case and If there's anyone that can suggest an approach, I am all ears, otherwise I might just have to try to do something myself ;o)

---

This basically mimics a simple set of Dr's offices.

*Starts out easy enough for AROs:*

- Group 1: administrators (of course)
- Group 2: caretakers
- Group 3: members

There is a "hasOne" relationship between groups and users (i.e. a user can only belong to one group).

*Now we use a tree structured ACO like [Aidan Lister considers](http://aidanlister.com/2009/05/implementing-row-level-access-control-in-cakephp/):*

```
/root
    /practice
        /practice_profile
        /practice_updates
        /patients
            /entries
            /profiles
            /other_things
```

Each caretaker will have access to a practice that includes his patients.  This gives the caretaker access to anything that the patient writes.  On top of this, the patient will **ONLY** be able to see/edit/etc... anything that he owns.  This wasn't specifically covered in any writing that I have read.  I know that with filesystem types of permissions this is commonplace, but I don't even want to go down that road...

With Auth/ACL in Cake's core, it doesn't really get into permissions like this.  It seems to say "well, if you're part of group X then you can perform function Y."  Therefore, it seems like any user that belongs to the `members` group would have access to all other members' content and all `caretakers` would have access to all practices.

Has anyone else come across this sort of use case?  Any suggestions for further reading?  Any known solutions?

EDIT:  So all of the answers were great, so upvotes all around.  I highly recommend looking at the post that I didn't find, supplied by bancer as it ended up pointing me to some cool things.  Ultimately, though, the answers were buried in the docs, I just didn't quite "get it" the first time around.  Also, there was an AHA moment when I read the [cakeqs](http://cakeqs.org/eng/questions/view/how_to_do_row-level_access_control) link.  So answer goes to Benjamin.

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030209/how-to-limit-data-to-users-who-own-it-without-limiting-admin-users-in-cakephp).

Comment: thanks for the answers guys (just logged in to see them).  I'll test some and look at some of those docs again and let you all know what I find out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will give you some inspiration. It's an extract of the acos table for a CMS I've developed. By using the otherwise apparently unused `model` column, I get an extra layer of control that lets me set accessibility to pages.

```
 id    parent_id  model  foreign_key  alias          lft  rght
 1462  1176       page   NULL         about-us       285  286 #display page url
 1515  1176       page   NULL         leo-test       291  292 #display page url
 1195  1176       NULL   NULL         ajaxSetStatus  261  262 #function
 1194  1176       NULL   NULL         walkTree       259  260 #function
```

Then I do something like this in the controller to see if the current user has permission to view the requested page (user defaults to Anonymous if not logged in):

```
function view($url=null)
{
    $nD = $this->NodeDescriptor->findByUrl($url);
    if(!$nD) $this->redirect(array('action'=>'error'));
    $user = ($this->Auth->user())?$this->Auth->user():'Anonymous';
    if(!$this->Acl->check($user,"{$url}"))
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
 ...
```

Comment: Of course you'll have to write some code to create the acos and to switch them on and off.

Comment: This is a great excerpt.  It's not *exactly* what I had in mind, but definitely something that I'll look into when I get my brain wrapped around the basics a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anybody else link to this other Stack Overflow question about ACL which suggests adding a new entry to the actionMap, "editown".

[editown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230/cakephp-acl-database-setup-aro-aco-structure/56537#56537)

Comment: That is an excellent one too.  I will have to look into how that will help in my specific situation, but I think something like that will be of great use.